# Function like KeyMap that combines values in case of key collisions

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

I am looking for a function that is similar to `KeyMap` in that it takes a function `fun` to transform each key.  However, when several different old keys map to the same new key, then `KeyMap` will only keep the last value.

Example:

```
KeyMap[First, <|{a, 1} -> 1, {a, 2} -> 2, {b, 1} -> 3|>]
(* <|a -> 2, b -> 3|> *)
```

Instead, I want to provide a combiner function `comb` to combine values:

```
keyCombine[First, <|{a, 1} -> 1, {a, 2} -> 2, {b, 1} -> 3|>, Identity]
(* <|a -> {1, 2}, b -> {3} *)

keyCombine[First, <|{a, 1} -> 1, {a, 2} -> 2, {b, 1} -> 3|>, Total]
(* <|a -> 3, b -> 3 *)
```

Is there a built-in function for this?  If not, what is the "best" implementation?  Take "best" to refer either to performance, elegance or compactness.

One possible implementation:

```
keyCombine[fun_, asc_?AssociationQ, comb_ : Identity] := Merge[MapAt[fun, Normal[asc], {All, 1}], comb]
```

---

**Benchmarking:**

```
SeedRandom[42];
aa = AssociationThread[RandomInteger[1000000, 100000], RandomInteger[1000000, 100000]];
```

Mine:

```
keyCombine[Mod[#, 5] &, aa, Total] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {7.48073, <|4 -> 9451454209, 2 -> 9485726007, 
  3 -> 9480421781, 0 -> 9443541021, 1 -> 9545354067|>} *)
```

Kuba:

```
keyCombineBy[aa, Mod[#, 5] &, Total] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.191946, <|4 -> 9451454209, 2 -> 9485726007, 
  3 -> 9480421781, 0 -> 9443541021, 1 -> 9545354067|>} *)

keyCombineBy2[aa, Mod[#, 5] &, Total] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {7.37696, <|4 -> 9451454209, 2 -> 9485726007, 
  3 -> 9480421781, 0 -> 9443541021, 1 -> 9545354067|>} *)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
keyCombineBy[assoc_?AssociationQ, by_, post_] := GroupBy[
    Normal@assoc, by@*First -> Last, post
]
```

```
keyCombineBy[<|{a, 1} -> 1, {a, 2} -> 2, {b, 1} -> 3|>, First, ff]
```

> ```
> <|a -> ff[{1, 2}], b -> ff[{3}]|>
> ```

This minimal modification makes it slightly faster:

```
keyCombineBy3[assoc_?AssociationQ, by_, post_] := GroupBy[
        Normal@assoc, by@*First , post @* Values
    ]
```

---

Or, alternatively (slow):

```
 keyCombineBy2[assoc_?AssociationQ, by_, post_
 ] := Merge[post] @ KeyValueMap[by@#1 -> #2 &] @ assoc
```

Comment: Benchmark added in original post.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks, I was aiming in elegance but good to know the difference.

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) to improve performance.

```
ClearAll[keyCombine];
keyCombine[fun_, asc_?AssociationQ, comb_ : Identity] :=
 asc //
   Query[Normal /* GroupBy[fun@*Keys]] //
  Query[All, (Values@# &) /* comb]
```

Here `Values@# &` is used instead of [`Values`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html) to circumvent the *syntax sugar* that works against our intention in this case.  Since we have a list of rules under each [`Key`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Key.html) from the first `Query` then `[All, Values]` maps all the way down to the values of the list of keys.  I think this is syntax sugar but it might be a bug (Ideas?).  In any case rolling our own pure function escapes this and lets us place `Values` on the list of rules.

With

```
SeedRandom[42];
aa = AssociationThread[RandomInteger[1000000, 100000], RandomInteger[1000000, 100000]];
```

Then

```
keyCombine[Mod[#, 5] &, aa, Total] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.158329, 
>    <|4 -> 9451454209, 2 -> 9485726007, 3 -> 9480421781, 0 -> 9443541021, 
>      1 -> 9545354067|>}
> ```

**Or, alternatively**

```
ClearAll[keyCombine2];
keyCombine2[fun_, asc_?AssociationQ, comb_ : Identity] :=
 Query[Normal /* GroupBy[fun@*Keys] /* Map[comb@*Values]]@asc
```

This replaces both the second `Query` and the pure `Values` function with `Map` in the first `Query`.

Then

```
keyCombine2[Mod[#, 5] &, aa, Total] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.16708, 
>    <|4 -> 9451454209, 2 -> 9485726007, 3 -> 9480421781, 0 -> 9443541021, 
>      1 -> 9545354067|>}
> ```

This is ever so slightly slower than `keyCombine` above but some may find it easier to read.

Hope this helps.